# Finding all critical points of $g(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus

> Find all critical points of the equation: $$g(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)e^{-x}$$

For this, I found the gradient of $g(x,y)$ which turned out to be $<(-x^2 + 2x -y^2)e^{-x}$ and $2ye^{-x}>$.

I set $2ye^{-x} = 0$ and I got $y  = 0$. I'm not sure if I was supposed to do that but I plugged that into $$(-x^2 + 2x - y^2) e^{-x} = 0 \implies-x^2e^{-x} = -2xe^{-x} \implies x=2$$
I'm not sure if I did this right but I ended up getting $(2,0)$ as a critical point.

Just wanted to verify that I got this right or not.

Comment: Tip: Use curly braces around your exponents. `e^{-x}` produces $e^{-x}$

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for that in MathJax documentation but I guess I missed it.

Comment: You've made a sign error in the first expression for $\nabla g = \langle (\color{red}{-}x^2-y^2+2x) e^{-x}, 2y e^{-x} \rangle$.  You're right to set the second component of $\nabla g$ to be zero, so that $y = 0$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter so plugging that into the first expression and getting 2 was also right? If so there should there only be one critical point?

Comment: You've missed $x=0$ as a solution.  Never divide by $x$.

Comment: The previous comment addresses your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can rewrite $g(x,y) =( x^2+y^2)e^{-x} = x^2e^{-x}+y^2e^{-x}.$

Now we compute the gradient of $g$:
$\nabla g = (2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}-y^2e^{-x},2ye^{-x})$ and we are looking for the points $(x,y)$  that make $\nabla g=\bar{0}$. So then

\begin{align}
\nabla g = \bar{0} \iff &(i)\ \ 2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}-y^2e^{-x}=0\\
&(ii) \ \ 2ye^{-x}=0
\end{align}
But $e^{-x} \neq 0$ for all $x$, so then from (ii) we get that $y=0$.
Now we substitute $y=0$ into (i) and get
$$ 2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}= 0 \iff e^{-x}x(2-x)=0 \iff x=0 \ \text{  or }\ x=2.$$

So the two critical points are $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting all the comments in  an answer:

for $y=0$ the equation $(-x^2 + 2x - y^2) e^{-x} = 0 $ becomes
$$
(-x^2 + 2x ) e^{-x} = 0  \quad \Rightarrow\quad (-x +2)xe^{-x}=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (-x +2)x=0
$$

so we have the two solutions $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$.